# AngularJS: Track the time spent in the web app then trigger an event on specific time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to track the time the user use the website and then I need to raise an event when the user have been on the site for 30 seconds. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: what have you written so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use Angular's built in `$timeout`

```
$timeout(function raiseEvent(){
   //do something here
}, 30000)
```

Answer (score 1):

where's the code? ..

heres an example without angular code, but feel free to use a $timeout and drop it inside of your app.run if you want it algularized.

```
// This event starts watching when document loads
// Any special event can work to trigger this instead

$(document).ready(function(){
    var countdown = 30000;

    // 30 Second  Event
    function thirty_second_event() {
        console.log("it's been " + (countdown/1000) + " seconds");
    }
    // Start the timer
    setTimeout( thirty_second_event, countdown );
});
```